# how are indices in the teapot.h arranged? glgravity sample for ios

Tags: ios, 3d, xcode5, opengl-es-2.0

I am an iOS programmer learning OpenGL ES to add capability of showing 3D models in my app.  I am working on the GLGravity sample and have been playing with the teapot.h model.  I am trying to understand how the data is organized in this model:  vertices and vertex normals make sense (although I am more used to the facet normals for the 3d mesh models).  I am not following the indices.

I was expecting to see triplets of integers to define what defines a triangular facet.  I cannot figure out how the indices are arranged here as they just seem like an array of numbers.  Also, I see -1 in there and that doesn't make sense as an index.  Of course, I didn't follow the run-length encoded (RLE) version of the indices either.

Can someone help me with this.

Many thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are triangle strips so indices are interpreted as [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip) — the first three indices define a triangle and then every subsequent index adds an additional triangle, reusing one edge of the previous triangle with some slight complexity as to vertex ordering.

`-1` indicates the end of a strip and is not passed to OpenGL. You can always draw arbitrary shapes using a single triangle strip through the use of degenerate triangles — you link strips through invented triangles with zero surface areas, which then contribute zero pixels to the display — but not everyone does.

In Apple's example you'll see they don't actually use `teapot_indices`, preferring `new_teapot_indicies` (sic) which pulls the count of vertices per strip out to the front rather than requiring you to walk through looking for the `-1`s.

So e.g. from `new_teapot_indicies` the first line is:

```
26, 1122, 1243, 1272, 1242, 1273, 1241, 1274, 1240, 1275, 1239, 1276, 1238,
1277, 1205, 1278, 1204, 1279, 1203, 1280, 1202, 1281, 1201, 1282, 1200, 1283,
1199
```

Which means "26 indices compose this strip; those indices are 1122, 1243, etc".

That compares to the original which was:

```
1122, 1243, 1272, 1242, 1273, 1241, 1274, 1240, 
1275, 1239, 1276, 1238, 1277, 1205, 1278, 1204, 
1279, 1203, 1280, 1202, 1281, 1201, 1282, 1200, 
1283, 1199, -1
```

So the code would have had to run through the array until it encountered the `-1` then spot that it had passed 26 indices while doing so and issue an appropriate draw call.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That answered my question very clearly.